# How do you create skins for the views slideshow?

Tags: views, theming

Supposedly, in Drupal 8 you can create custom styles for your slideshow (Views Slideshow), which the README refer to as "skins".

Normally I'd use a css, but the module annoyingly includes a style section, which overwrites anything type in the css, so I have to use a skin.

The problem now is that there's no documentation about it whatsoever, I can't even get rid of the default style!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's important this issue is filed with the mentioned module's issue queue to have the docs updated there, not here on Drupal Answers. I guess that basically this hasn't changed much from what can be found in [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow/issues/1427310) for Drupal 7. Have you tried that already?

Comment: [Are these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSkdA.png) the styles you're talking about? If yes, just append `!important` to your CSS. Ex: `#edit-style-options-views-slideshow-cycle-advanced-options-table { width: 100% !important; }`